# is it possible to add duplicate values to usn column? this is the table i have created,how to add data something like i have shown in the example?

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[studentdb] (
    [usn]         VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
    [name]        VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [collegename] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [eventid]     VARCHAR (15) NOT NULL,
    [passwd]      VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [email]       VARCHAR (75) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_studentdb] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([usn] ASC, [eventid] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([eventid]) REFERENCES [dbo].[eventdb] ([eventid])
);
```

is it possible to add duplicate values to usn column?
this is the table i have created,how to add data something like i have shown in the example?

```
USN  EVENTID
1     100
2     100
3     200
1     200
3     100
4     100
5     100
5     200
```

Comment: Have you tried an insert statement?

Comment: You might want to walk through some introductory tutorials for SQL.  An `INSERT` statement is pretty basic.

Answer (score 0):

Your `PRIMARY KEY` is compound key. It is based on two columns `([usn] ASC, [eventid] ASC)` so as long as pair is unique you can insert it.

In your example:

```
1     100
2     100
3     200
1     200
3     100
4     100
5     100
5     200
```

every pair is unique.

For inserting data use `INSERT INTO` syntax like:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[studentdb](
      [usn],
      [name],
      [collegename],
      [eventid],
      [passwd],
      [email])
VALUES (1, 100, ...), -- rest of values
       (2, 100, ...),
       ...;
```

Comment: oh my god! i made a mistake in code behind file....but thank you for giving answer..